# imagecolorset not working

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I'm creating a website where user can edit images. For changing the colour of a png file, I use the following code.

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng ("image/white-round.png");
$index = imagecolorclosest ( $im,  255,255,255 ); 

imagecolorset($im,$index,0,0,255); 

$imgname = "image/white-round.png";

imagepng($im,$imgname );
imagedestroy($im);
```

I'm getting `$index`, but `imagecolorset($im,$index,0,0,255);` is not working.

Comment: "Not working" how? What happens?

Comment: Im not getting the result. And I just tried 
if(!imagecolorset($im,$index,0,0,255)){ 
echo "hii";exit;
}
and it enters inside the if condition.So I guess its not working.Is it due to any other factor ?

Comment: What result are you getting? Use `var_dump()` to find out

Comment: nothing.it doesn't display anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imagecolorset() doesn't work for me.

But imagefill() works fine for me.

Refer http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/11/2/8